# Benefit of slist over vector?

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector

What I need is just a dynamically growing array. I don't need random access, and I always insert to the end and read it from the beginning to the end.

slist seems to be the first choice, because it provides just enough of what I need. However, I can't tell what benefit I get by using slist instead of vector. Besides, several materials I read about STL say, "vectors are generally the most efficient in time for accessing elements and to add or remove elements from the end of the sequence". Therefore, my question is: for my needs, is slist really a better choice than vector? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that slist is part of the sgi STL distribution, but not part of the C++ Standard library. There is a std::forward_list in C++0x/C++1x (next C++ version) though.

Comment: Thanks, I also learned that just now.

Comment: There is also a std::list<T> class in STL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For starters, `slist` is non-standard.

For your choice, a linked list will be slower than a vector, count on it. There are two reasons contributing to this:

1. First and foremost, cache locality; vectors store their elements linearly in the RAM which facilitates caching and pre-fetching.
2. Secondly, appending to a linked list involves dynamic allocations which add a large overhead. By contrast, vectors most of the time do *not* need to allocate memory.

However, a `std::deque` will probably be even faster. [In-depth performance analysis](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/vector_vs_deque.aspx) has shown that, despite bias to the contrary, `std::deque` is almost always superior to `std::vector` in performance (if no random access is needed), due to its improved (chunked) memory allocation strategy.

Comment: What makes you think slist will be slower, and where is this mysterious (and applicable for all applications) performance evaluation?  http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html says, "The main way in which deque differs from vector is that deque also supports constant time insertion and removal of elements at the beginning of the sequence."  But the OP explicitly said he was never doing insertion or removal at the beginning.

Comment: Also, I find it hard to believe you couldn't find the docs for slist.

Comment: Matthew: Guilty as charged: I was lazy. About your accusation: what the SGI article says is simply outdated; it was believed to be true but benchmarks simply show that `deque` performs better than `vector` even in vector-typical usage. I've linked the relevant analysis.

Comment: Indeed. If we are not handling with very few data items, i would recommend deque too. It's not a coincidence that deque is the default underlying sequence of std::stack. However, for few items, vector should be the default.  (std::stack doesn't know how much items will be pushed, so it's going the safe way with deque).

Comment: Btw, this is another prime example why calling the standard library "STL" is going to result in much confusion. I never do it, because there are many "STL" meanings, but only one C++ Standard Library meaning.

Comment: +1: if there is doubt between using a vector or a (s)list, deque is probably the right choice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you are always reading beginning to end, [slist](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Slist.html) (a linked list) sounds like the way to go.  The possible exception is if you will be inserting a large quantity of elements at the end at the same time.  Then, the vector could be better if you use reserve appropriately.

Of course, profile to be sure it's better for *your* application.

Comment: That sounds like the opposite of what I've written (and backed up with data) so it's probably not right.

Comment: You didn't provide any data on slist, only the vague promise of it, and a comparison of two other (besides slist) structures.

Comment: Again: sorry. I'm a bit stupid apparently, I confused the benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Austern (author of "Generic Programming and the STL" and general C++ guru) is a strong advocate of singly-linked lists for inclusion in the forthcoming C++ standard; see his presentation at http://www.accu-usa.org/Slides/SinglyLinkedLists.ppt and his long article at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2543.htm for more details, including a discussion of the trade-offs involved that may guide you in possibly choosing this data structure. (Note that the currently proposed name is `forward_list`, though `slist` is how it was traditionally named in SGI's STL & other popular libraries).

Answer (score 2):

I'll second (or maybe third...) the opinion that `std::vector` or `std::deque` will do the job. The only thing that I will add is a few additional factors that should guide the decision between `std::vector<T>` and `std::list<T>`. These have a lot to do with the characteristics of `T` and what algorithms you plan on using.

The first is memory overhead. `Std::list` is a node-based container so if `T` is a primitive type or relatively small user-defined type, then the memory overhead of the node-based linkage might be non-negligible - consider that `std::list<int>` is likely to use at least `3 * sizeof(int)` storage for each element whereas `std::vector` will only use `sizeof(int)` storage with a small header overhead. `Std::deque` is similar to `std::vector` but has a small overhead that is linear to `N`.

The next issue is the cost of copy construction. If `T(T const&)` is at all expensive, then steer clear of `std::vector<T>` since it cause a bunch of copies to occur as the size of the vector grows. This is where `std::deque<T>` is a clear winner and `std::list<T>` is also a contender.

The final issue that usually guides the decision on container type is whether your algorithms can work with the iterator invalidation constraints of `std::vector` and `std::deque`. If you will be manipulating the container elements a lot (e.g., sorting, inserting in the middle, or shuffling), then you might want to lean towards `std::list` since manipulating the order requires little more than resetting a few linkage pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean std::list by "slist". Vectors are good when you need fast, random-access to a sequence of elements, with guaranteed contiguous memory, and fast sequential reading (IOW, from the beginning to the end). Lists are good when you need fast (constant-time) insertion or deletion of items at the beginning or end of the sequence, but don't care about the performance of random-access or sequential reading.

The reason for the difference is the way the 2 are implemented. Vectors are implemented internally as an array of items, which needs to be reallocated when its size/capacity is reached on adding an item. Lists are implemented as a doubly-linked list, which can cause cache-misses for sequential reading. Random-access for lists also requires scanning from the first (or last) item in the list, until it locates the item you're requesting.

Comment: Just realize, slist, a singly linked list, is not standard? It does appear in HP/SGI STL though.

Comment: Unfortunately, std::list is a doubly-linked list, which is totally unnecessary given the OP's described requirements.  Otherwise, I agree with this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good job for *std::deque* to me. It has the memory benefits of a vector like contiguous memory allocation for each "slab" (good for CPU caches), no overhead for each element like with std::list and it does not need to reallocate the whole set as std::vector does. Read more about [std::deque here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/vector_vs_deque.aspx)